# python catching error from decorated function

Tags: python

Is it possible to catch an exception from f_1 function in f_3 ? Now I am getting exception only from f_1 function.

```
def f_1(a):
    if a < 0:
        raise Exception("a < 0")
    else:
        return a + 1

def f_3(func):
    try:
        result = func
    except Exception as e:
        print("catched: " + e)
    else:
        return result
    finally:
        print("finally...")


print(f_3(f_1(-1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the exception occurs while `f_1(-1)` is being evaluated, *before* that result gets passed as an argument to `f_3`, so there is no `try/catch` in place when the exception occurs. You can work around this by passing the function *and* its arguments to `f_3` and then calling the function with its arguments inside `f_3`:

```py
def f_1(a):
    if a < 0:
        raise Exception("a < 0")
    else:
        return a + 1

def f_3(func, *args):
    try:
        result = func(*args)
    except Exception as e:
        print("catched: " + str(e))
    else:
        return result
    finally:
        print("finally...")

print(f_3(f_1, -1))
```

Output:

```
catched: a < 0
finally...
None
```

Note that you can't add `e` to a string directly, you need to convert it to a string first i.e.

```py
print("catched: " + str(e))
```

or just output it on its own:

```py
print("catched: ", e)
```